# css3-mediaqueries.js -> How to include from google code?

Tags: javascript, html, media-queries, google-code

I'm using the the HTML5Shiv from google code on my site. I'm including it like this …

```
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

I also need to include css3-mediauqeris.js that is also available on google code.
However I can only find the download link for the js-file but can't find an actual link to directly load it from google-code.

http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Any ideas?

Thank you for your info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is [not officially supported](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#Libraries) by Google for its Libraries API, but you should be able to include the most recent version via a vanilla script tag using the downloadable version from code.google.com (warning, not the safest way to load JS).

```
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/files/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```